# What are the Integer Solutions to a Specific Hyperbola?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

I was trying to find the integer solutions for this equation: $$2xy=x+33$$ This is particularly interesting as it is not simplified to something like $\frac{33}{x}$, so it can not be (at least I believe so) solved by factoring. As always, I would like methods that don't involve factoring.

Comment: "As always..." what do you mean by that ? Could you be more explicit ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a new factoring technique.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Because if I'm working on a new factoring technique that uses this, why would I want to factor? It would defeat the entire point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation is equivalent to
$$0\equiv x+1\mod{2}\implies x\text{ is odd}$$
Hence we have
$$2y(2k+1)=2k+34$$
$$y(2k+1)=k+17$$
$$y=\frac{k+17}{2k+1}$$
Now the function $(k+17)/(2k+1)$ is decreasing as the denominator increases faster than the numerator. Hence we only need to try $k$ such that $(k+17)/(2k+1)\ge1$ as greater $k$ will not allow $y$ to be an integer. This means that all of the solutions are given by
$$k=0,x=1,y=17$$
$$k=1, x=3, y=6$$
$$k=5, x=11, y=2$$
$$k=16, x=33, y=1$$

Comment: How did you find those, by testing?

Comment: what about $k=0$?

Comment: Yes, as I stated, the value of $y$ is decreasing so you only need to test $0\le k\le16$ and you can conclude that there are no other solutions to the equation.

Comment: @PeterForeman bust what if for $2xy=x+n$, $n$ gets really big?

Comment: It all depends on the number of factors of $n$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

It is equivalent to:
$$(2y-1)x=33=3\times 11=1\times 33$$

Comment: But, is there a way to do it without factoring?